# PHP Ping multiple IPs at once and timed intervals

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with hosts and ports and I was wondering if there was a way in strictly PHP, to ping all of them at once and log it every 30 minutes.

EDIT: Forgot to add.. I'm a beginner

Comment: Well, you cannot ping ports, but you can ping the IP addresses.

Comment: I already have a way to ping them and return stuff, I just want to be able to ping them at timed intervals and log it, instead of when I refresh the page (that's when it pings it currently)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use a task scheduler like cron, but if you really want to repeat a task with a specified interval within the script itself, you could combine a loop with [`sleep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) or [`usleep()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usleep.php):

```
while (true) {

/*
  Perform pings here and write output to some file
  If the functions write directly to stdout, you can use
  ob_start() and ob_get_clean() to catch the output
  and write it to a log file instead.
*/

sleep(1800); // 30 minutes in seconds
}
```

With this method you should disable PHP's time limit setting, either in php.ini or with `set_time_limit(0)`.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you already have an existing script that performs the function you need. I'd recommend modifying this script (if needed) to run from a command line instead of as a web page. I.e., don't rely on things like $_GET or $_POST. Run one check, log the results, and exit. Then just add a [`cron`](http://www.scrounge.org/linux/cron.html) job to run the script every 30 minutes.

Comment: How would I modify it to be ran from a web host?